# making image a bi-color image where ColorOne >=128 and ColorTwo <128

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

```
% Clean up the BlackAndWhiteCheckerBoard.bmp by making it a true
% bi-color image where
% ColorOne >=128
% ColorTwo <128
% If the 
% Input: ColorOne, ColorTwo, BlackAndWhiteCheckerBoard.bmp
% Output: CleanCheckerBoard, CleanCheckerBoard.bmp <-- not a typo!
```

Here is what the checkboard image looks like:

[image: blah]

I'm really unsure what to do. Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is `BlackAndWhiteCheckerBoard.bmp` a gray image or a color one?

Comment: Also curious how can a filename like `CleanCheckerBoard.bmp` be an output? Shouldn't that be an input too? Because it seems you want to save the output bi color image by that name, don't you?

Comment: @Divakar - The question is poorly worded, but the input image is a grayscale image. When you look at the image on `tinypic` (I've also included it in this post), we interpret it as black and white, but if you do a histogram of the image, it is not **purely** black and white. There are some intensities within the vicinity of 255 and 0. As such, we are trying to convert this image to represent an image of only **two** intensities - One with `ColorOne` and the other with `ColorTwo`.

Comment: @CarlSTennison - Do you require any more further assistance?  Have I answered your question adequately?  If I have, please consider accepting my answer.  You can do that by clicking on the checkmark icon that is just below the up and down arrows to the left and the top of my post.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done very easily with Boolean operations.  First read in the image, then use Boolean operations to set your pixels accordingly.  Following the steps of your question definition, and assuming that you set your working directory in MATLAB to be where you have placed the image, do the following:

```
ColorOne = ...; %// You define here
ColorTwo = ...; %// You define here
im = imread('BlackAndWhiteCheckerBoard.bmp'); %// Read in the image
CleanCheckerBoard = im; % // Copy input to output
%// Set colours according to spec
CleanCheckerBoard(im >= 128) = ColorOne;
CleanCheckerBoard(im < 128) = ColorTwo;
%// Save your image
imwrite(CleanCheckerBoard, 'CleanCheckerBoard.bmp');
```

The question is poorly worded, but my assumption is that any intensities that are `>= 128`, you wish to set to `ColorOne` and those intensities that are `< 128` you set to `ColorTwo`.  If I have interpreted this incorrectly, please leave me a comment and I will adjust my code accordingly.

The above code will read in your image, and you must specify what `ColorOne` and `ColorTwo` are.  After, I make a copy of this image to the output variable that is part of the spec, and then I use Boolean operations to do what I just mentioned in the previous paragraph.  After, I take this new image and save this to a file called `CleanCheckerBoard.bmp` as specified in the spec.

Comment: How about this one-liner - `CleanCheckerBoard = ColorOne*(im1>=128) + ColorTwo*(im<128)`? +1

Comment: @Divakar - Yup that'll work :)   I seem to have the habit of clarifying the problem, and you elegantly proposing a solution :)

Comment: and I hate confusions and try to stay away from the confusing ones :) So it seems, we complement each other quite well for the benefit of SO askers :)